# how to escape single quote in batch script calling for powershell command

Tags: powershell, batch-file

before you say anything, I did a search, couldn't find anything that helped me, I also tried a few things on my own, not a thing worked so far.

I'm not sure if it's powershell or batch related to be honest... Anyway...

**I have the following script:**

```
setlocal
if "%IsCollection%"=="y" set browsetext=Please choose the location where the 
games for %GameTitle% are installed:
if not "%IsCollection%"=="y" set browsetext=Please choose the location where 
%GameTitle% is installed:

set "psCommand="(new-object -COM 'Shell.Application')^
.BrowseForFolder(0,'%browsetext%',0x00000200,0).self.path""

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%I in (`powershell %psCommand%`) do set "choice=%%I"
```

My problem is that when the variable **%GameTitle%** include a single quote, like for example **"Director's Cut"** it prevents from the **browseforfolder** window from opening, resulting in an error.

How can this be fixed?

Thank you.

**Just a note:** The %GameTitle% variable is read from an external .ini file if it matters.

Comment: Single-quotes aren't interpreted by cmd.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 What exactly are you trying to say here?, I fail to see your point, care to explain?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substitute the single quote with two:

```
set GameTitle=%GameTitle:'=''%
```

Comment: @GerhardBarnard Well, maybe not, since it also involves powershell, anyway, don't want to say something stupid on a matter I don't understand but the fact is, that suggestion actually worked, I added that code, right below the `setlocal` and it solved the problem, it works and it displays the variable content correctly with one single quote.